# Unable to select multiple values using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table id="laptop_detail" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:18px" class="ha">Touchscreen</td>
        <td class="val"><span class="no_icon">No</span></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:18px" class="ha">Water Dispenser</td>
        <td class="val"><span class="no_icon">No</span></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:18px" class="ha">Colour / Material</td>
        <td class="val">Grey</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my xpath:

```
$x('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Touchscreen")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text() and //*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Water Dispenser")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text() and //*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Colour")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')
```

But my xpath returns "true" instead of my requirement "No, No, Grey". I know there is something wrong with my xpath but i am unable to understand it.

**EDIT:** Okay i had a little success, I was able to get "No, No" using this xpath:

```
$x('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Touchscreen") or contains(. ,"Water")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()')
```

but unable to get "Grey" as that value is not inside span tag.

Comment: Why not just to add one more expression for Grey using | operator.

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi did not knew if I can do that.

Comment: Then try solution below, it must work for you.

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix to your solution (I've added | operator):

```
//*[@id="laptop_detail"]/tr/td[contains(. ,"Touchscreen") or contains(. ,"Water")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text() | //*[@id="laptop_detail"]/tr/td[contains(. ,"Colour / Material")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```

You can use little bit more easy syntax (run faster) if it is acceptable for your logic.

```
/table[@id="laptop_detail"]/tr/td[@class='val']/span/text() | /table[@id="laptop_detail"]/tr/td[@class='val']/text()
```